# How to avoid e-05 in python using a variable

Tags: python, formatting, precision

I know that you can avoid getting outputted, for example, 1e-10 using '{:.10f}'.format(1e-10), but I would adjust to take the decimal places as a variable (the 10f and e-10) depending on what the the value after e is...

I've used this code to find the value of decimal points needed

```
a = 6.789e-05
b = str(a)

if b[5] == 'e':
    if b[7] == '0':
        decimal_places = int(b[8])
        
    else:
        decimal_places = int(b[7]+b[8])
```

But I am struggling to figure out how I could no adjust the decimal places of the variable a using what I've found? As replacing '10f' with the decimal_places variable doesn't work... any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple function to get number precission:

```py
def precision(num):
    n = str(num).split('e')
    if len(n) == 1:
        return 0
    x = 0 if len(n[0].split('.')) == 1 else len(n[0].split('.')[1])
    return x + abs(int(n[1]))
```

Then you can use string formatting to print your number to desired precission:

```py
a = 6.789e-05
b = 6e-05
c = 3.5
d = 5
print('{num:.{precision}f}'.format(num=a, precision=precision(a))) # 0.00006789
print('{num:.{precision}f}'.format(num=b, precision=precision(b))) # 0.00006
print('{num:.{precision}f}'.format(num=c, precision=precision(c))) # 3.5
print('{num:.{precision}f}'.format(num=d, precision=precision(d))) # 5
```

Comment: Would it be possible to return this value as a number? rather than str, without getting rid of the added precision?

Comment: @djluc101 this is just a type of writing value to a string, the underlying numerical value is still the same. If you try to convert the result to `float()`, it will be back to starting notation.

Comment: exactly my problem, I need to use this value as price to create orders through a trading API (Binance). Binance is feeding me prices but python is returning them in this form: 6.789e-05. I need to convert this into decimal form and use it to execute orders according to numerical conditions, so I need the added precision and to be able to manipulate it numerically.

Comment: You can still use this format to check your conditions, it works just as a regular numerical value. I don't understand to what operations you would need this precise format when the underlying value is the same. Maybe I could help better if you show me what numerical conditions you need these values for.

Comment: essentially, Binance will not accept price values in the form 6.789e-05, but when I receive price information from Binance python converts it into this form. I use this price information to create new orders, and the price parameter in the order function cannot take values in the form 6.789e-05, but they must be numbers, not strings.